# Type A or 1 and goto the same case

Tags: batch-file

I'm just learning batch scripting and now I am asking if I can do something like type `a` or `1` and `goto` the same case.

```
:start
echo Type in:
A = A
B = B
C = C

set /p option=
echo.

if /i '%option%' == 'A' goto caseA
if /i "%option%" == "1" goto caseA
if /i '%option%' == 'B' goto caseB
if /i "%option%" == "2" goto caseB
if /i '%option%' == 'C' goto caseC
if /i "%option%" == "3" goto caseC

cls
echo invalid Enter
goto start

:caseA
echo I am here because you typed A or 1
echo.
goto end

:caseB
echo I am here because you typed B or 2
echo.
goto end

:caseC
echo I am here because you typed C or 3
echo.
goto end

:end
echo End
pause
```

Is there anyway to minimize this area of the code:

```
if /i '%option%' == 'A' goto caseA
if /i "%option%" == "1" goto caseA
if /i '%option%' == 'B' goto caseB
if /i "%option%" == "2" goto caseB
if /i '%option%' == 'C' goto caseC
if /i "%option%" == "3" goto caseC
```

I mean, I could use something like a template for this code salad. But maybe there is something easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to forget about using `Set /P` for input, in favor of `Choice`.

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo 1. A
Echo 2. B
Echo 3. C
Choice /C 1a2b3c /N
If ErrorLevel 5 Echo You entered 3 or C&Pause&Exit /B
If ErrorLevel 3 Echo You entered 2 or B&Pause&Exit /B
Echo You entered 1 or A&Pause&Exit /B
```

Your specific example would therefore look a little more like this:

```bat
:Start
Echo Type in:
Echo 1. A
Echo 2. B
Echo 3. C
Choice /C 1a2b3c /N
If ErrorLevel 5 GoTo CaseC
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo CaseB
Echo You are here because you typed A or 1
Echo(
GoTo End

:CaseB
Echo You are here because you typed B or 2
Echo(
GoTo End

:CaseC
Echo You are here because you typed C or 3
Echo(

:End
Echo End
Pause
```